In telegram app in iPhone, element of long list getting cut unexpectedly while scrolling
In my telegram React/Next JS app in iPhone, element of long list getting cut unexpectedly while scrolling.
Some time list element cutting half or from anywhere, which seems to me render issue, because if it hide from CSS/JS complete element will either show or hide.
It happens some time and some time its working fine. I tried so many workaround but not able to fix correctly.
below code i am using to prevent app close in telegram while scrolling down.
 html.iphone-device{
      overflow: hidden ;  
      overscroll-behavior: none;
      body{
        height: 100dvh !important;
        overscroll-behavior: none;
        overflow: auto;
        touch-action: initial !important;
        position: relative;
        scroll-behavior: unset;
    }
    }



I fixed that problem by setting to html tag position: fixed; Like:
html {
  position: fixed;
  height: auto !important;
}

